# Please explain this picture

Tags: history

my mother cut this image out of a newspaper or magazine during a stay in Pakistan in the early 70's:

[image: Magazine cut-out]

Unfortunately she does not remember what it is about and we are sorry that we can not read the captions.

Clearly there is some reference to Islam or islamic culture. We are curious what story it is telling so we might understand why she kept it.

Regards, Marian

Comment: Well I am not sure if this is on-topic. The image shows the [Shahada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shahada), the [Kaaba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaaba) and the [Green dome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Dome). The building at the bottom left is the shrine (over grave) of someone (local sufi saint?) named within the poster as [Kanwan Wali Sarkar](https://www.google.com/search?q=kanwan+wali+sarkar) and the person seems to be the same.